# Load file shows insert statements in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to load data into a table in MySQL from a text file.

I've created the table manually and now I want to import data into it.

This is the contents of the file I am trying to import:

```
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Executive Orders', 1996, '0-425-15863-2');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Forward the Foundation', 1993, '0-553-67507-9');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Foundation', 1951, '0-553-80371-9');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Foundation and Empire', 1952, '0-553-29337-0');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Foundation\'s Edge', 1982, '0-553-29338-9');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('I, Robot', 1950, '0-553-29438-5');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Isaac Asimov: Gold', 1995, '0-06-055652-8');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Raibbow Six', 1998, '0-425-17034-9');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Roots', 1974, '0-440-17464-3');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Second Foundation', 1953, '0-553-29336-2');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('Teeth of the Tiger', 2003, '0-399-15079-X');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('The Best of Issac Asimov', 1973, '0-449-2-829-X');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('The Hobbit', 1937, '0-261-10221-4');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('The Return of The King', 1955, '0-261-10237-0');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('The Sum of All Fears', 1991, '0-425-13554-0');
INSERT INTO books VALUES ('The Two Towers', 1954, '0-261-10236-2');
```

I am using this command to import the file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/library.sql' INTO TABLE books COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

There is no error and the data in the table looks like this:

```
MariaDB [library]> select * from books;
+---------------------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Title                     | year_published | ISBN                 |
+---------------------------+----------------+----------------------+
| INSERT INTO books VALUES  |              0 | INSERT INTO books VA |
| INSERT INTO books VALUES  |              0 | INSERT INTO books VA |
| INSERT INTO books VALUES  |              0 | INSERT INTO books VA |
| INSERT INTO books VALUES  |              0 | INSERT INTO books VA |
| INSERT INTO books VALUES  |              0 | INSERT INTO books VA |
| INSERT INTO books VALUES  |           NULL | NULL                 |
+---------------------------+----------------+----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

This is what I want the data to look like:

```
MariaDB [library]> select * from books;
+--------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Title                    | year_published | ISBN          |
+--------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Executive Orders         |           1996 | 0-425-15863-2 |
| Forward the Foundation   |           1993 | 0-553-67507-9 |
| Foundation               |           1951 | 0-553-80371-9 |
| Foundation and Empire    |           1952 | 0-553-29337-0 |
| Foundation's Edge        |           1982 | 0-553-29338-9 |
| I, Robot                 |           1950 | 0-553-29438-5 |
| Isaac Asimov: Gold       |           1995 | 0-06-055652-8 |
| Raibbow Six              |           1998 | 0-425-17034-9 |
| Roots                    |           1974 | 0-440-17464-3 |
| Second Foundation        |           1953 | 0-553-29336-2 |
| Teeth of the Tiger       |           2003 | 0-399-15079-X |
| The Best of Issac Asimov |           1973 | 0-449-2-829-X |
| The Hobbit               |           1937 | 0-261-10221-4 |
| The Return of The King   |           1955 | 0-261-10237-0 |
| The Sum of All Fears     |           1991 | 0-425-13554-0 |
| The Two Towers           |           1954 | 0-261-10236-2 |
+--------------------------+----------------+---------------+
16 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*library.sql* seems to have the content of a dump file and in this case you need to use MySQL restore not [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). The LOAD DATA statement reads rows from a text file into a table.

As you are using windows I will give an example.

I created a test database and books table saved the content of `library.sql` in my desktop in the following path `C:\Users\erges\OneDrive\Desktop\fileee\library.sql` and in the end on my `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin` path in the command line i executed ,

```
mysql -u root -p test < C:\Users\erges\OneDrive\Desktop\fileee\library.sql
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That worked. Thank you!